# C Initializing Matrix

Tags: c, enums, initialization, c-preprocessor

I have the following matrix;

```
Vertex axisVertices[] =
    {   
        { { x_0, y_0, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // origin
        { { x_Max,  y_0,  0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // eixo y
        { { x_0,  y_Max, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } } // eixo x       
    };

#define x_0 0.0f
#define y_0 0.0f
#define x_Max 1.5f
#define y_Max 1.7f
```

I need to be able to initialize the matrix like this. The only possible way of doing this in **C** is by defining either an enum, or using #define because initializing like this can't be used with a constant.

The problem is, I need to be able to change the values `x_Max` and `y_Max` throughout the code, so `#define` wont work in this case. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Whats wrong with passing parameters to the `#defines`?

Comment: once i define x_0 for example, i cant change its value. isn't it right?

Comment: did the answer help? Or is there something you are still confused about? Also do you need to change x_0 at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to `#defines` to create [macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html)

For example you can do

```
#define INIT(x_0, y_0, x_Max, y_Max) \
         { { { x_0, y_0, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, \
         { { x_Max,  y_0,  0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, \
         { { x_0,  y_Max, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } } }
```

Which you can use like this

```
 Vertex axisVertices[] = INIT(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f, 1.7f);
```

Then all occurrences of `x_0` will be replaces by `0.0f`. Just like passing parameters to functions.